# sas 4gl sql how to join the tables

Tags: sql, join, 4gl

I am new in programming and I have to do some task which looks like this:
I have two tables for example:

**TableA**

```
+-------+
| name  |
+-------+
| name1 |
| name2 |
| name3 |
+-------+
```

**TableB**

```
+-------+-------+
| name  | tips  |
+-------+-------+
| name1 | tips1 |
| name1 | tips2 |
| name1 | tips3 |
| name2 | tips4 |
| name2 | tips5 |
| name3 | tips6 |
+-------+-------+
```

now I want to have a table like this:

**TableC**

```
+-------+---------------------+
| name  |        tips         |
+-------+---------------------+
| name1 | tips1, tips2, tips3 |
| name2 | tips4, tips5        |
| name3 | tips6               |
+-------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Search for EXAMPLES - JOIN

Answer (score 0):

```
data TableC;
    set TableB;
    by name;

    length t_tips $ 1000;
    retain t_tips;

    if (first.name) then
        do;
            t_tips=strip(tips);
        end;
    else
        do;
            t_tips=strip(tips) ||", "||strip(t_tips);
        end;

    if (last.name) then output;
    drop tips;
run;
```

Comment: This is what I needed. ;]